# Which approach should I use to store translation of products in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm creating an application where products will be created by my customer (something like an e-commerce website), so I obviously require translated descriptions stored in database, I can't force my customer to learn git/yml.

I have two ideas on how to correctly localize descriptions (and eventually product name) and store them in database, but if there is a well-known approach that I should use, I would be really happy to know it.

The first idea seems the most logical for me, but I would like to make it "transparent" to me, I don't want to write joins everywhere, so some suggestion on how to achieve this, if it's the correct one, would be appreciated.

**Idea 1:**
Create a database table `products` (with `name` and `description` field set maybe to the default locale language), then a `products_translations` table which contains a table structured in this way:

```
products_translations
- id
- locale
- product_id
- name
- description
```

As an example: `product_translation: { id: 1, locale: 'en', product_id: 3, name: 'toy', description: 'play' }`

But I want to access to translations without the requirement to write a lot of IFs everywhere. So if I write product.name it should return en or it based on current locale.

*Bonus:* Are there any gems that can help me to achieve this?

**Idea 2:** The other idea is to have a table with `name_locale1`, `name_it` and so on, but I don't like this approach because will pollute my model objects with fields and I will have a giant table.

However, in this way I can avoid join on every query for that object.

If there is a greater approach which I don't know about (a database pattern or similar), it's ok that too, I'm not forced to strict to only these two ideas, however I have to choose between the two and I really don't know which could be better.

**Important:** I would like to keep translations stored in yml files, except for dynamic contents, which obviously require translations in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with PinnyM that the first approach is the better of the two, but rather than implement your own schema, I would highly recommend you implement [Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) where most of the structural decisions have been taken for you (and by Mr Fuchs himself, no less). Also, with the rails helpers, you just call something like `product.name` on a model instance and the gem will figure out how to display it in the correct locale, awesome!

Comment: PinnyM answer is great, but this gem is somewhat fantastic. I think this is definitely the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is the recommended one.  As you surmised, the second approach is not as clean and requires more work on the coding end with no real gain since you still have to join on this monster table.  To the contrary, the first method requires at most one join, while the second approach requires a join on each attribute you may want to add localization support.

You can simply append a scope on all your product calls such as:

```
scope :for_locale, lambda{|locale| joins(:product_translations).
                                   where(product_translations: {locale: locale || 'en'}) }
```

and pass in the session locale (or wherever you are storing it).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, expecially to understand how it works. However tigrish have solved completely the issue with that gem.